# ASP.NET Sample Websites

Tags: asp.net

I have primarily worked with Data-Driven Applications. Is there a place on the net where I can find complete ASP.NET Data Websites, so that I can incorporate part of these web applications into my own?

Comment: I know its not rs. I havn't asked for scripts / code either. Am just asking for assistance if something like www.asp.net exists? I have tried Google too, so was just curious if any of the peers know of a similar website. There must be many i am sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.net pet shop.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16693

this one hosted on codeplex is for .net 3.5 
http://petshopvnext.codeplex.com/releases/view/9782

Comment: this sample doesn't get installed. Actually i am trying to install it on Win Server 2008 Operating System, and its giving me error while installing. Can you suggest other websites too please

Answer (score 1):

www.asp.net itself has many sample applications, you can try that too